# how to get domain name ip address by dns not hosts file in ruby

Tags: ruby, dns, puppet

## /etc/hosts

1.1.1.1 test.example.com

## DNS

2.2.2.2 test.example.com

I use below function get hosts ip address, i want get dns ip address ,when someone modify my hosts error ip, puppet facter get correct ip to overwrite

IOSocket.getaddress('test.example.com')

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to solve. You could inoculate yourself against shenanigans in `/etc/hosts` by tailoring `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Resolv::DNS](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv/DNS.html)

Example:

```
require 'resolv'
dns = Resolv::DNS.new( :nameserver => ['8.8.8.8'] )
ip = dns.getaddress( 'test.example.com' )
```